# How to handle different exceptions in PL/SQL differently?

Tags: oracle, exception, plsql

My stored-procedure is looping executing different statements. I want to handle the following situations:

1. When the statement returns nothing (`no_data_found`), I want to quietly skip the rest of the loop (`continue`).
2. When the statement causes an error of any type, I want to report it, and then skip the rest of the loop (`continue`);
3. When the statement finds rows, I want to report it.

The code looks like:

```sql
...
LOOP
    stmt := 'select * ......';
    BEGIN
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE stmt;
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN NULL;
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
            dbms_out.put_line(stmt || ': ' || SQLCODE);
        CONTINUE;
    END;
    dbms_out.put_line('Found! Use: ' || stmt);
END LOOP;
```

The above elicits no errors, but the `Found`-line is printed for *every* loop-iteration, including for statements, that yield no results...

Why is the `CONTINUE`-directive ignored -- am I wrong expecting the directive to be obeyed for *any* exception -- be it `NO_DATA_FOUND` or anything else?

Comment: You'd only know if a query returns 0 rows if you try to fetch data from it.  If you know the structure of the query's result set, you'd do an `execute immediate` with an `into` or `bulk collect into` with an optional `limit` depending on whether the query returns a single row or multiple rows.  If the statement is completely dynamic so you don't know the structure of the result in advance, you'd need to use `dbms_sql` to describe the result before fetching data which becomes **way** more complicated.

Comment: It sounds like you are really only concerned with the number of rows that any of the queries return rather than the actual results.  If so, you should be able to wrap the query in a `select count(*) from ( <<query>> )` and then fetch the result into a single `l_cnt` variable.

Comment: Khm, so simply doing `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE stmt` is not enough to know, whether it yields any rows? I thought, using `NO_DATA_FOUND` would look nicer -- and be easier to understand for future readers of the procedure...

Ok, let me try the `count(*)` route. BTW, is it `count(*)` or `count(1)` -- I've seen both...

Comment: Either would work.  I prefer `count(*)`.  Depending on the version, there may be slight microoptimizations in Oracle for implementing `count(*)` vs `count(1)` but that basically never makes a functional difference.

Comment: @MikhailT. - if you simply do `execute immediate stmt` (where `stmt` is a query) [is not even executed](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/lnpls/EXECUTE-IMMEDIATE-statement.html#GUID-C3245A95-B85B-4280-A01F-12307B108DC8), it's only parsed. As Justin said you would have to fetch all the rows to see how many there were, unless you count them; and you still have to fetch that count result into something. If you only care about zero or more-than-zero rather than the actual number of rows you could add a rownum stopcheck, or maybe use `exists`.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the use of `exists`? I 'd like for the code to be readable...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your exception block, the action for your `NO_DATA_FOUND` handler is NULL - so it executes the NULL statement (i.e. does nothing) and falls out of the BEGIN-END block, hitting the `dbms_out.put_line('Found! Use: ' || stmt);` statement. The only handler which will execute `CONTINUE;` is the `WHEN OTHERS`.

One way to get the behavior you describe is to do a `SELECT COUNT(*)...` into a numeric variable and then just check to see how many rows are returned:

```
DECLARE
  csr     SYS_REFCURSOR;
  nCount  NUMBER;
BEGIN
  LOOP
    stmt := 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT * from ... WHERE ...)';

    OPEN csr FOR stmt;

    FETCH csr INTO nCount;

    CLOSE csr;

    IF nCount > 0 THEN
      dbms_out.put_line('Found! Use: ' || stmt);
    ELSE
      dbms_out.put_line(stmt || ': ' || SQLCODE);
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Of course this is not really valid as there's no way for the value of `stmt` to change, but I suspect your "real" code handles that.

Comment: Why is not it hitting the `CONTINUE` statement, which is after both `WHEN`-s in the `EXCEPTION`-block?

Comment: In a PL/SQL exception block, each `WHEN` block is independent of the others. They do not fall through from one to the next. If the program enters a WHEN trap in an EXCEPTION statement and there's no CONTINUE or RAISE, after the last statement in the WHEN is executed the next statement to be executed will be whatever follows the `END` statement of the block, even if there are other `WHEN` traps in the EXCEPTION statement. So in your code, after `WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN NULL;` is executed the next statement to be run is `dbms_out.put_line('Found! Use: ' || stmt);`. That's just how PL/SQL works.

Comment: So, as written, my `CONTINUE` is never, actually, reachable, is it?

Comment: As written, the `CONTINUE` is part of the `WHEN OTHERS...` handler. The indentation is a bit misleading.

Comment: Ah! That's because I thought -- coming from languages like C or Java -- that only one statement can follow `THEN` (unless it is a `BEGIN .... END`). That's why I thought, `CONTINUE` will be hit after either of the `WHEN`s is processed... Thanks!